# commutative diagram with one injective map

Tags: commutative-algebra, diagram-chasing

Let $A,B,C,D$ be R-modules. Suppose there is a commutative diagram as the following.

$A\to B$ is the injective, $A\to C$ and $B\to D$ are surjective.

Is $C\to D$ injective?

Comment: To be clear, you are assuming there are maps $f:A\to B$, $g:A\to C$, $h:B\to D$, and $i:C\to D$ such that $hf=ig$?

Comment: @EricWofsey Yes. I do not think it will induce injective map.

Comment: Try with $0\neq A=B=C, D=0$.

Comment: @Mohan, Yes. That is a counterexample. Thanks.